# Working with GRASS gis in pyQGIS

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-grass-plugin

I am looking for a way to loop through GRASS gis v.net.distance in QGIS. I want to iterate over all the 3 layers which has multiple features at the same time, and print the shortest distance for each of the layers in a CSV format. Can anybody please refer me to some resources or links with examples of how to do it in PYTHON? is it possible to do it with PYQGIS at all?

[image]